# In ADX, how do I flatten my data to filter out null values in a specific time window?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data coming into ADX from a single device that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| dateTime                    | latitude | longitude | temperature |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-07-17T20:55:00.824313Z | 47.5783  | -78.1692  |             |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-07-17T20:55:00.824311Z |          |           | 60          |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-07-17T20:54:01.000258Z | 47.5653  | -78.2692  |             |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-07-17T20:53:00.877956Z |          |           | 62          |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Every other update from this source either contains the lat/long or the device's temperature.

If I want to get a snapshot of the device's complete state in a given time window, how do I flatten this data? For instance, if I wanted the latest device state, I'd like to get back a single row that contains:

```
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| dateTime                    | latitude | longitude | temperature |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-07-17T20:55:00.824313Z | 47.5783  | -78.1692  |      60     |
+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

one option would be to "split" the table into 2 (one with the lat-lon, and one with the temperature), then `join` both parts:

```
let T = datatable(id:string, dateTime:datetime, latitude:double, longitude:double, temperature:double)
[ 
    "a", datetime(2020-07-17T20:55:00.824313Z), 47.5783,      double(-78.1692), double(null),
    "a", datetime(2020-07-17T20:55:00.824311Z), double(null), double(null),     60,
    "a", datetime(2020-07-17T20:54:01.000258Z), 47.5653,      double(-78.2692), double(null),
    "a", datetime(2020-07-17T20:53:00.877956Z), double(null), double(null),     62
];
T
| where isnotnull(temperature)
| summarize arg_max(dateTime, temperature) by id
| join (
    T
   | where isnotnull(latitude)
   | summarize arg_max(dateTime, latitude, longitude) by id
) on id
| project id, dateTime, latitude, longitude, temperature
```

Comment: that definitely works, but I'm wondering if it'll be scalable as we add more telemetry columns to the table?